# Getting updated values in ng-repeat Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using ng-repeat, which is getting values from my db and putting it. Now i insert these values into input text which i update. Now i have a save button, which saves the updated values. I am not getting the updated values when i press the save button. Please guide me through this.

```
<div ng-controller="education" ng-init="getEducationDetails();">
    <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="row" ng-repeat="values in education"
                        style="margin-left: 20px; margin-right: 20px; margin-top: 10px;">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <h4>
                                <small>Degree</small>
                            </h4>
                            <input type="text" id="educationDegree" name="educationDegree"
                                value="{{values.education_degree}}" style="width: 90%;" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <h4>
                                <small>Year</small>
                            </h4>
                            <input type="text" id="educationYear" name="educationYear"
                                value="{{values.education_year}}" style="width: 100%;" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                            <h4>
                                <small>University</small>
                            </h4>
                            <input type="text" id="educationUniversity"
                                name="educationUniversity"
                                value="{{values.education_university}}" style="width: 100%;" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12" style="margin: 20px;">
                    <button ng-click="educationSave();" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
                </div>
</div>
```

on `educationSave()` i save the values. But when i get the education array in the `educationSave()` method, i get the old array. How can i get the updated array, after i adjust some of the input types

Here is how i get the values:

```
$scope.getEducationDetails = function()
            {
                $http({
                    method : 'GET',
                    url : '/getEducationDetails'
                }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        $scope.education = data.resultSet;
                        alert($scope.education);
                }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                });
            };
```

Here is my controller method:

```
    $scope.educationSave = function() {
        var educationArray = JSON.stringify($scope.education);
        //I then save this educationArray
    };
```

Comment: Hi @Stealz What would I suggest you is using NgGrid for that purposes , it has a  **Edit On Focus Cell Selection**  property just as you need . [link](http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/ )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not using `ng-model` to bind your actual input value to controller. From [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input):

> HTML input element control. When used together with ngModel, it provides **data-binding**, input state control, and validation.

Try something like this in your markup for each `input`:

```
<input type="text" id="educationDegree" name="educationDegree"
                            ng-model="values.education_degree" style="width: 90%;" />
```

See little [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/iluzyanin/32jon5zr/)

Comment: Absolutely, it works. I am actually new to Angular, i am learning data binding. Thanks !!